# How to set properties for a dependent gradle task

Tags: gradle

I want to set up a "generic" task which will build app bundles for a number of platforms (it uses javafxpackager). The mechanics of the task apply to creating all platform bundles, but the difference is in the various property used by the task.

I had thought that I would create separate higher level tasks for each platform in which the platform specific properties would be set, and then call/execute/(substitute the correct gradle lingo here) the generic task. E.g.,

```
task buildMacBundle(dependsOn: ['macBundleConfig', 'buildAppBundle']) << {
  // set Mac-specific properties (project.ext properties?)
  // call/invoke/execute or whatever the mechanism is called, buildAppBundle task
    buildAppBundle.mustRunAfter macBundleConfig
    println "building a Mac app bundle"
}

task macBundleConfig << {
    println "executing macBundleConfig"
    ext {
        nativeType = "dmg"
        bundleAppName = 'My App'
    }
    delete ("${buildDir.name}/dist/${bundleAppName}.dmg")
}


task buildWindowsBundle << {
  // omitted for brevity, but just like buildMacBundle except for property values
}

task buildAppBundle << {

    println "nativeType: ${project.ext.nativeType}" // it stumbles here!

    def cmd = [
        "${javapackager}",
        "-deploy",
        "-native", "${project.ext.nativeType}",
        "-name",
        "${project.bundleAppName}",
        "-outdir",
        "${buildDir.name}${File.separator}dist",
        "-outfile",
        "MyApp",
        "-srcdir",
        "${buildDir.name}${File.separator}${libsDir.name}",
        "-appclass",
        "org.pf.app.MyApp"
    ]

    println cmd.join(" ")

    def javapackager = exec {
        workingDir "${project.projectDir.absolutePath}"
        commandLine cmd
    }
}
```

But when I run "buildMacBundle", I get

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':buildAppBundle'.
> cannot get property 'nativeType' on extra properties extension as it does not exist
```

How do I define the properties in the specific task which then invokes the generic task?

Answer (score 8):

I faced a similar problem, and I found that if you switch

```
ext {
    nativeType = "dmg"
    bundleAppName = 'My App'
}
```

with

```
project.ext {
    nativeType = "dmg"
    bundleAppName = 'My App'
}
```

it should work.
From what I gather, it's a scoping problem - in the first case you set the property for the `Task`, and in the second case, for the `Project`.

---

By the way, I think that `buildAppBundle.mustRunAfter macBundleConfig` will run too late for you, as it is part of the `buildMacBundle` task, so the order of running will be:

1. macBundleConfig
2. buildAppBundle
3. buildMacBundle

and only during 3 will the configuration `mustRunAfter` of `buildAppBundle` will be changed.

Answer (score 5):

I solved it with this:

```
gradle.taskGraph.whenReady {taskGraph ->
    if (taskGraph.hasTask(buildMacBundle)) {
        project.ext.nativeType = "dmg"
    } else if (taskGraph.hasTask(buildWindowsBundle)){
        project.ext.nativeType = "exe"
    }
}
```

To me, this is the simplest way, but far from intuitive. It took a great deal of googling to stumble on this in

the User Guide: 6.13. Configure by DAG (whatever DAG is?)

I suspect there's an easier way, but it's not in writing a plugin for sure. Were I to be creating something to be used in more than one build.gradle script, I'd consider a plugin to be the right way to go, but here, in just one build.gradle build script, it's overkill.

Comment: This is the wrong approach. The solution I proposed does not involve implementing a plugin.

Answer (score 2):

You can try create GradleBuild Task and invoke desired task with given project properties.

```
task someTask(type: GradleBuild) {
    tasks = ['taskToParametrize']
    startParameter.projectProperties = ['parameterName': 'parameterValue']
}
```

Then you can query for property:

```
project.properties['parameterName']
```

See [Gradle build logic docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/organizing_build_logic.html#sec:external_build).

Answer (score 2):

I came across this solution:

```
task meta1 {
    doLast {
        user.property="variant1"
    }
}

task meta2 {
    doLast {
        user.property="variant2"
    }
}

meta1.finalizedBy buildTask
meta2.finalizedBy buildTask
```

Where `buildTask` is the task that does the work, and in this example `user.property` must be set before the task runs to configure the target configuration. There are two meta tasks, each of which sets the appropriate value for the property, then requires the build task to be run after it, via the `finalizedBy` command.

Gradle

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for (though I put the finalizedBy inside the task itself).  Something like `task a { doLast { b.prop="c" }
finalizedBy b
}`.
 Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Tasks aren't supposed to configure stuff. This is what build scripts and plugins are for. What you probably want is a *task type* (i.e. a task "template" implemented as a class) that has some configuration properties (`nativeType`, `bundleAppName`, etc.) based on which it creates an app bundle. A build script or plugin can then declare multiple tasks of that type (e.g. one for each platform) and configure them as necessary. Alternatively, you could also implement multiple task types, perhaps extending a common base class.

Comment: Way too complex an answer. These tasks _are_ defined in a build.gradle "build script". I should not have to write a plugin to accomplish something so simple. In ANT this is really straightforward. I thought gradle was an advancement over ANT, but this looks retrograde.

Comment: The solution I proposed can be implemented in a single build script, and doesn't involve implementing a plugin.

Comment: An example would be helpful. Just from the answer, I wouldn't know how to start. This makes this answer one of the least helpful despite it is likely to be the best.

Comment: without an example, this answer is not quite useful