# App Engine exploded war folder issues with Gradle

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gradle, intellij-idea, war

I've got a Gradle App Engine project that I'm using the Google ApppEngine Dev Server to debug.

I'm not sure why, but the exploded war artifact in IntelliJ was pointing to a different folder to the folder that Gradle was using for the exploded war. I got around this by specifying a matching folder in Gradle using

```
war {
    explodeWar.setDestinationDir(file("./build/libs/exploded/backend-local-test.war"))
}
```

Everything was working smoothly for debugging. When it came to deployment, the `appengineDeploy` task is again looking for the exploded war in a different folder rather than the one I'm specifying in Gradle.

I've has a look, but I can't see a property I can set to specify the folder that `appengineDeploy` should look at for the exploded war.

**So to summarise**

Google ApppEngine Dev Server is pulling the folder to use for the exploded war from the artifact in IntelliJ. Changing the war path in Gradle doesn't seem to affect the exploded war path for the artifact.

`apppengineRun` and `appengineDeploy` seem to always use `./build/exploded-backend` as thier exploded war path

How can I get the artifact in IntelliJ and therefore the Google ApppEngine Dev Server to use the same path as the Gradle tasks?

Answer (score 2):

I've solved this for now using the solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24022322/how-to-set-properties-for-a-dependent-gradle-task/25605443)

```
war {
    gradle.taskGraph.whenReady {taskGraph ->
        if (taskGraph.hasTask(appengineDeploy)) {
            explodeWar.setDestinationDir(file("./build/exploded-backend"))
        } else {
            explodeWar.setDestinationDir(file("./build/libs/exploded/backend-local-test.war"))
        }
    }
}
```

If anyone has a more elegant solution, then please post it.